# SQL ACCESS (need ideas and help about a query)

Tags: sql

I am new at access SQL and i need help with some query. What i want is to find those customers that prefer a car (manufacturer and model) from `prefer_to_buy` AND `prefer_to_rent` that no one else prefer.

For example if 2 customers prefer toyota aygo must not be in the result table.

> customer(customer_id,name)
>
> prefer_to_buy(customer_id,manufacturer,model)
>
> prefer_to_rent(customer_id, manufacturer,model)

I have tried a lot of ways including exists and i know there must be about 2-3 subqueries but i cant get it to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem definition is very vague, so the answer is also sort of generic. You should try to create a Left Outer Join on `customer` table and, for example, a "`prefer_to_buy`" Table using `customer_id` as a join field, and include:
`customer_id,name` from the left table and `manufacturer,model` from the right table. The same logic applies to `prefer_to_rent` Table: you can actually combine these 3 Tables in a single Access SQL query using the aforementioned Outer Joins.

Hope this may help. Best regards

Comment: this was a exercise in a book i have, but so far i have learned about subquery ( with a lot in and exists, never done outer join) , so i guess there would be an easy solution or something? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of parts to cover here. First, you could use the `union` operator to treat `prefer_to_buy` and `prefer_to_rent` as a single table (possibly with an additional literal "column" to indicate preference type). Once you've done this, you could use the `exists` operator to make sure no other customers prefer this car:

```
SELECT c.name, p.manufacturer, p.model
FROM   customer c
JOIN   (SELECT customer_id, manufacturer, model
        FROM   prefer_to_buy
        UNION 
        SELECT customer_id, manufacturer, model
        FROM   prefer_to_buy) p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   prefer_to_buy pb
                   WHERE  c.customer_id != pb.customer_id AND
                          p.manufacturer = pb.manufacturer AND
                          p.model = pb.model) AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   prefer_to_rent pr
                   WHERE  c.customer_id != pr.customer_id AND
                          p.manufacturer = pr.manufacturer AND
                          p.model = pr.model)
```

Comment: hmmm tried that , ( also tried to understand the code, to be honest is a little to dificcult for me) but i keep getting an error in FROM clause...

Comment: of course:) it just says Syntax error in FROM clause. (Error 3131).and it gets the mouse over the first  join. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @user4959146 hmm... I don't have an Access database handy, unfortunately, but this query runs like a charm on MS SQL Server. Sorry :-(

Comment: No problem, thank you very much for your time and effort

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do to two joins one on prefer_to_buy AND one on prefer_to_rent.
Next, you need to check if any one else would like the same manufacturer and model. Do this with a exist

```
SELECT *
FROM customer AS c 
  JOIN prefer_to_buy AS pb ON c.customer_id = pb.customer_id 
  JOIN prefer_rent AS pr ON c.customer_id = pr.customer_id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'x' FROM prefer_to_buy AS pb1 WHERE pb.manufacturer = pb1.manufacturer AND pb.model = pb1.model AND pb.customer_id <> pb1.customer_id) 
 AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'x' FROM prefer_to_rent AS pr1 WHERE pb.manufacturer = pr1.manufacturer AND pb.model = pr1.model AND pb.customer_id <> pr1.customer_id)
```